# Not getting updated state value in socket callback react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, socket.io

I have listend an event in customhook and when that event works, I have to do some logic there with state.but now I only get empty array every time that event callback works.

```
const useChatHistoryList = () => {
  const sk = useSocket();
  const [chatList, setChatList] = useState([]);
  const [end, setEnd] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    sk.emit('chatlist');
  }, [start]);

 
  useEffect(() => {
    const onChatListReceived = data => {
      const _data = JSON.parse(data);
      setHistoryLoading(false);
      setChatList(_data);
    };

    const onChatListToUpdateReceived = data => {
      const _data = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(chatList);//getting only empty array everytime
    };

    sk.on('chatlist', onChatListReceived);
    sk.on('chatlistToUpdate', onChatListToUpdateReceived);
    return () => {
      sk.off('chatlistToUpdate');
      sk.off('chatlist');
    };
  }, []);

  return { chatList,end};
};
```

Comment: Where have you updated the `state` ? I cannot see the `setState` called.

Comment: I called setState in useEffect and , it is working fine. I just want to know why I didn't get that updated state in socket callback.@PR7

Comment: Because `setState()` updates the state asynchronously. Your callback is getting executed before the state is updated.

Comment: that is correct , but that socket callback work only that event emitted right? In my case that event is emitted only after data gotfrom the api and presssing a button will emmit that event. @PR7

Comment: It's difficult to figure out the issue from the above code, probably should add more code.

Comment: I have added more code @PR7

Comment: Where do you emit `chatlistToUpdate` event ?

Comment: Socket listening is working perfectly, just want to know why I couldn't access the state value from callback.

Comment: Just to be clear, by asynchronous I did not mean the API call but the `setChatList()` itself. I hope this is how the current implementation is.

Comment: @PR7 if possible , could you please explain with code solution please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to log your data first to make sure the data is there, then set your state with the data.

```
const [state, setState]= useState([]);

const _onReceived = (data) => {
  // Here is your data from socket
  console.log(data);

  // Then set state value with data
  setState(data);
}

useEffect(()=>{
  // Init socket listener
  socket.on("event", _onReceived);
}, []);

// This effect will runs everytime state value is set (including when setting default value)
useEffect(()=>{
  // Actual 'state' value
  console.log('State value: ', state);
}, [state]);
```

==========================

**Edit, related to your updated codes in the question**

Your `onChatListToUpdateReceived` function brings empty default value to the listener even later when it’s updated, your listener will still recognize chatList value as an empty string. Try to move out `onChatListToUpdateReceived` outside useEffect.

```
const onChatListToUpdateReceived = data => {
  const _data = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(chatList);//getting only empty array everytime
};

useEffect(() => {
  const onChatListReceived = data => {
    const _data = JSON.parse(data);
    setHistoryLoading(false);
    setChatList(_data);
  };

  sk.on('chatlistToUpdate', onChatListToUpdateReceived);

  return () => {
    sk.off('chatlistToUpdate');
    sk.off('chatlist');
  };
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  sk.off('chatlistToUpdate');
  sk.on('chatlist', onChatListReceived);
}, [chatList]);
```

Comment: I want to access the state in callback not update the state and also updated some code.

Comment: I move out the **onChatListToUpdateReceived** function from the useEffect , but still getting default empty array.

Comment: Updated by adding new useEffect that depends to chatList value changes.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used `socket.io` before but this is what I meant by asynchronous update. From your code, it looked to me like your callback is getting called before the state is updated. So to solve this, I added a `useEffect()` with `chatList` as a dependency so that callback gets called every time `chatList` gets updated. I hope this makes sense.

```js
const useChatHistoryList = () => {
  const sk = useSocket();
  const [chatList, setChatList] = useState([]);
  const [end, setEnd] = useState(true);

  const onChatListReceived = data => {
    const _data = JSON.parse(data);
    setHistoryLoading(false);
    setChatList(_data);
  };

  const onChatListToUpdateReceived = data => {
    const _data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(chatList); //getting only empty array everytime
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    sk.on('chatlist', onChatListReceived);
    sk.on('chatlistToUpdate', onChatListToUpdateReceived);
    return () => {
      sk.off('chatlistToUpdate');
      sk.off('chatlist');
    };
  }, []);

  // Emit chatlistToUpdate whenever chatList is updated
  useEffect(() => {
    sk.emit('chatlistToUpdate');
  }, [chatList]);

  return {
    chatList,
    end
  };
};
```